# make text disappear/appear when list item is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

this is the list

```
<div>
    <a href="#hig"><button class="tag-btn">High blood pressure  Diabetes</button></a>
    <a href="#hih"><button class="tag-btn">High cholesterol</button></a>
    <a href="#thy"><button class="tag-btn">Thyroid disorder screening</button></a>
    <a href="#car"><button class="tag-btn">Cardiovascular risk assessment</button></a>
    <a href="#can"><button class="tag-btn">Cancer screenings</button></a>
    <a href="#bre"><button class="tag-btn">Breast screening</button></a>
    <a href="#lun"><button class="tag-btn">Lung screening</button></a>
    <a href="#col"><button class="tag-btn">Colon screening  Cervical screening</button></a>
    <a href="#pro"><button class="tag-btn">Prostate screening</button></a>
    <a href="#add"><button class="tag-btn">Addiction screening</button></a> 
</div>
```

this are the corresponding divs

```
<div class="serv-text fl-wrap one" id="hig">
b
</div>
<div class="serv-text fl-wrap one" id="hih">
c
</div>
<div class="serv-text fl-wrap one" id="thy">
d
</div>
<div class="serv-text fl-wrap one" id="car">
e
</div>
<div class="serv-text fl-wrap one" id="can">
f
</div>
<div class="serv-text fl-wrap one" id="bre">
g
</div>
<div class="serv-text fl-wrap one" id="lun">
h
</div>
<div class="serv-text fl-wrap one" id="col">
e
</div>
<div class="serv-text fl-wrap one" id="pro">
j
</div>
<div class="serv-text fl-wrap one" id="add">
k
</div>
```

and this is my css

```
#obs, #hig, #hih, #thy, #car, #can, #bre, #lun, #col, #pro, #add {
  display: none; 
}

#obs:target, #hig:target, #hih:target, #thy:target, #car:target, #can:target, #bre:target, #lun:target, #col:target, #pro:target, #add:target {
  display: block;
}
```

With the code above it worked well but i am using a sticky header so the div showing appears under the header making it inconvenient for the users who have to always scroll down.

Is there a better way to achieve this having the sticky header in mind?

Maybe it will work with java script i don't know...

Help me out fam...

Answer (score 0):

The header hides or obscures the divs you want to display do I understand this correctly. If that's the case you could just add a topmargin to the maindiv where you want to show the elements so that the div starts when the header ends. Maybe I don't understand your problem, but I think that would be the easiest way, or you rebuild your layout with a grid, bootstrap or something like that which takes care of arranging the divs for you.